# Changing colors in jquery accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I have jquery code that generates a light to a dark green transition in LIs - so the first LI is the light green, and it flows to the last LI which is dark green.

This is the code that makes this happen:

```
var _gStart     = 167,
_gEnd = 70,
_bStart     = 70,
_bEnd = 30;

$(".accordion li .text").each(function(index){
var _g = Math.round(_gStart - (index * ((_gStart - _gEnd) / (_length - 1))));
var _b = Math.round(_bStart - (index * ((_bStart - _bEnd) / (_length - 1))));
$(this).children('a').css('background-color','rgb(0,' + _g + ','+ _b + ')');
});
```

Can anyone help turn the colors to fade from white to grey? like #dddddd grey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since white is `255,255,255`, you'll need to modify it to increment the `r` (red) value as well, and provide the appropriate end values for gray.

```
var _rStart = 255,
    _gStart = 255,
    _bStart = 255,
    _rEnd   = 215,
    _gEnd   = 215,
    _bEnd   = 215;

$(".accordion li .text").each(function(index){
  var _r = Math.round(_rStart - (index * ((_rStart - _rEnd) / (_length - 1))));
  var _g = Math.round(_gStart - (index * ((_gStart - _gEnd) / (_length - 1))));
  var _b = Math.round(_bStart - (index * ((_bStart - _bEnd) / (_length - 1))));
  $(this).children('a').css('background-color','rgb(' + _r + ',' + _g + ','+ _b + ')');
});
```